# How to display user-modified list of projects for selection?

Tags: android, saving-data

Okay, so what I'm looking to do in the application I am writing, is allow the user to create "projects", each project has a custom name defined by the user, and each project containts the user's defined values for several variables. (some stored in arrays, which I already have coded in the application).

Then what I need to do is when the user clicks on a button that says, "open saved project", it will list all the saved projects the user has created.

I've looked into sqlite in android, and it may work although documentation is scarce, but I still cannot find an answer to my question on how to display the custom saved projects on an android screen, so the user can select from all of his saved projects. As you see, I can't hard code this in an xml.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think SQLite is the best option for storing projects. If you're fine with reading the android documentation, you can see the package [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).